# Consumer not polling any messages with random group.id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have the exact same issue described here but with the Java API: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/275

To summarize, my client is producing to a topic which is consumed, processed and answered on another topic which my client is subscribed to. 1) I began configuring a fixed `group.id` for testing purpose and the client consumed well the messages but 2) when I change it for a Java random UUID to obtain one consumer group per client, it does not poll any messages.

I checked the topic in both cases with kafka-console-consumer which shows the expected messages but only with random `group.id` they were not polled. I am polling every 100 ms until a client-defined timeout e.g 60 seconds is over. I printed the consumer assignment between each poll to check that the client was effectively subscribed to the topic partitions and it was fine in both cases.

Any idea on this consumer issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the config property auto.offset.reset to "earliest". This will consume the topic from the earliest available record when you're using a new group.id. The default is "latest", which means it will skip all the existing records and only consume any new records that are produced to that topic.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset